# Writing numpy array to file- byte-order issue?

Tags: python, numpy, io

I'm trying to write a numpy array to file, but the file format is such that every value must contain only the 8 bytes required to represent a 64-bit float.

As best I can tell, ndarray.tofile(array), with array.dtype = 'float64' is not accomplishing this, so how can I do this quickly?

Comment: Why do you think that `tofile()` is not doing what you want? Can you show the actual code you are using and the output you get? Also I don't get how the title of the question is related to the question itself. AFAIK if you have problems with endianess then you can use the `byteswap()` method to change the endianess of an array(note that files do *not* keep this information, hence you should *know* which endianess was used when saving a file in order to open it from a different machine).

Comment: Please show us what you did to come to this conclusion. And keep in mind the warning from the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html): "This is a convenience function for quick storage of array data. Information on endianness and precision is lost, so this method is not a good choice for files intended to archive data or transport data between machines with different endianness."

Comment: endianness was the problem, fixed with byteswap(). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`tofile` already creates the binary file that you describe. Are you sure you are calling it correctly; if you're opening the file in your code, did you remember to open it in binary mode? Here is an example of `tofile` working as expected:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype='float64')
>>> a
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])
>>> a.tofile('foo')
```

Inspecting the file reveals it to be 24 bytes long, and with the contents corresponding to little-endian 64-bit IEEE 754 floats:

```
$ hexdump -C foo   
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 3f  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40  |.......?.......@|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 08 40                           |.......@|
00000018
```

Comment: What if we need the reverse - big-endian?

Comment: @javadba I suppose you can use [`byteswap`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.byteswap.html) then, but why would you need to write big-endian floats? Do you have an actual big-endian architecture that would read them?

Comment: I'm not actually sure. I'm trying to write python / read swift and not working. I did try `byteswap()` and that did not work either. But I have not carefully studied this yet.

Comment: @javadba If you're not sure, then you're almost certainly running on a little-endian platform (for both python and swift) and your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: quite likely.  the swift side is behaving quite unexpectedly e.g. generating hugely bloated binary files.  thanks